# Get-Set accessors for array property, with index handled

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this class property

```
public object[] array { get; set; }
```

I'm able to get and set the entire array, as well as alter the individual items within the array.

How can I also achieve this with manual get-setters?

None of the answers to these 3 posts:

[How do define get and set for an array data member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751871/how-do-define-get-and-set-for-an-array-data-member)

[Array property syntax in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031299/array-property-syntax-in-c-sharp)

[Get/Set Method for Array Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320021/get-set-method-for-array-properties)

cover what I'm needing to do.

```
object[] array;
public object[] Array {
    get { return array; }
    set { array = value; }
}
```

would allow me to get and overwrite the entire array, but I wish to have indexal access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I overload the \[\] operator in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424669/how-do-i-overload-the-operator-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public sealed class ArrayWrapper<T> {
   private readonly T[] _array;
   public ArrayWrapper(T[] array) {
      if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
      _array = array;
   }

   public T this[int i] {
      get { return _array[i]; }
      set { _array[i] = value; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you think this is simpler? http://stackoverflow.com/a/424677/7759514

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Call a function when values are set/get. I think I'll try the get/setValue functions first

Comment: Um, you can run whatever you want inside the set/get code I put above. How is that not brain-dead simple?

Comment: What I was getting at was it's possible over-complication. It's only about 4 lines, though.

Comment: Nevermind.... For some reason I thought the Set/GetValue functions the answer-poster included were generic methods for array modification; seems not--the OP had defined them. Your post is the *actual* answer.